# Ajax validation in form update in yii

Tags: javascript, yii

I have a form for both creation and editing some fields.I am using Ajax validation for that before submitting the form like

```
 <?php $form=$this->beginWidget('CActiveForm', array(
            'id'=>'candidates-profiles-form',
            'enableAjaxValidation'=>true,
                        'enableClientValidation'=>true,
    'clientOptions'=>array(
        'validateOnSubmit'=>true,
        'validateOnChange'=>false,
         'beforeValidate'=>"js:function(form) {         
            if((form.data('submitObject')[0].id ) == 'cancel'){
            alert('cancalclicked');
                this.validateOnSubmit = false;
        this.validateOnChange = false;
        this.beforeValidate = ''; // the problem is caused by this line
        form.submit();
        return false;

                }
                else{
                  alert('submitclicked');
                return true;

                }

        }",    
        'afterValidate'=>"js:function(form, data, hasError) {
       if(hasError) {
                alert('We have detected some input errors and has not saved your data. Please click Ok to correct them.');
                return false;
            }
            else {          
                if(confirm('We have validated your input and we are ready to save your data. Please click Ok to save or Cancel to return to input.'))
                    return true;
                else
                    return false;
            }
        }",)


)); ?>
```

After creation it is perfectly coming in afterValidate function and works fine.But after editing it is not all coming in afterValidate. But it is coming in  beforeValidate and submitting the form with out reaching afterValidate .

Comment: Do you have $this->performAjaxValidation($model); on the update action in the controller?

Comment: Yes,I am having $this->performAjaxValidation($model); in my actionupdate in controller.But the strange thing is , it is saving all the modifications but not redirecting after saving using $this->actionAdmin();

Comment: Thanks for the hint,In my  controller i have check  if (isset($_POST['candidates-profiles-grid_c0']))            
  {}  i have put my $this->performAjaxValidation($model); there.That was the problem.When i put it outside its worked fine.Thanks again.

Comment: No problem I added it as an answer so you can mark it as the correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you have $this->performAjaxValidation($model); in your controller for that action.